The expectation of $L^2_x$
In some problems, we use $$\langle L^2_x\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(\langle L^2\rangle-\langle L^2_ z\rangle)$$
But in other problems, we use
$$\langle L^2_x\rangle=\frac{1}{4}\langle[L^2_+ + L^2_- +2(L^2-L^2_z)]\rangle.$$
They often give different results. What is the actual formula? And why they differ? As $L^2=L^2_x +L^2_y +L^2_z$ since $L^2_x$ and $L^2_y$ are equally likely we can take the the expectation value of above equation as
$$\langle L^2\rangle=2\langle L^2_x\rangle +\langle L^2_z\rangle$$ then consequently we get,
$$\langle L^2_x\rangle=(\langle L^2\rangle-\langle L^2_ z\rangle)/2.$$
But if we use ladder operators we have $L_x=(L_+ + L_- )/2$ following some algebra we get
$$\langle L^2_x\rangle=\frac{1}{4}\langle[L^2_+ + L^2_- +2(L^2-L^2_z)]\rangle$$
So my questions is why these two equations don't match.
EDIT:I HAVE ASSUMED WAVE FUNCTION IS PREPARED IN THE SIMULTANEOUS EIGEN BASIS OF $L^2$ and $L^2_z$

"some problems", "give different results" Please specify them. Do you expect us to read your mind??

$\langle L_x^2 \rangle \neq \langle L_y^2 \rangle$ in general.  For example, for a state with $L = 1, L_x =1$, $\langle L_x^2 \rangle = \hbar^2$ while $\langle L_y^2 \rangle = \hbar^2/2$.

I concur with the sentiment that it would be beneficial to include where you've seen both definitions of $\langle L_x^2\rangle$.

Somewhat an inversion of Michael's comment, $\langle L_x^2\rangle=\langle L_y^2\rangle$ requires the problem to have a symmetry.

Yes i have mentioned in the edit..wave function is in the eigen basis of L² and $L²_z$..so symmetric about X and Y..

If you have an eigenbasis of $L^2$ and $L_z$, $\vert\ell m\rangle$, then $\langle\ell m\vert L_\pm^2\vert\ell m\rangle\equiv0$ due to the orthogonality of the states. In such a case, your second equation appears to reduce to the first, no?

I don't know where you got those formulas from, they might apply to some specific system, but in general it is always true that
$$
S^2 = S_x^2 + S_y^2 + S_z^2 
\\
= \frac{1}{2}(S_+S_- + S_-S_+) + S_z^2
$$
from which you can solve for $S_x^2$. You can also use
$$
S_x^2 = \frac{1}{4}(S_+ + S_-)^2.
$$
